# primefaces calendar value is undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I try to get primefaces calendar value in javascript this is my xhmtl page on the below i put javascript metod startPrint() i call this metod  onclick action so i get calendar value undefined but same thing works with h:inputHidden so i guess problem on p:calendar component

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:calendar id="datesr" value="#{protocolCnt.detail.prCreateDate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>  
            <p:commandButton value="Çap et" style="margin-left: 30px"   onclick="startPrint()" icon="ui-icon-printPrt"/>
            <h:outputScript  library="javascript" name="printJS.js" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Console output: datesr undefined printJS.js?ln=javascript:35

```js
function startPrint() {    

  var datesr = document.getElementById('datesr').value;
  console.log('datesr ' + datesr);

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getDate()`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6922ec428149c29b84c66f8934f34001589996e8/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/mobile/widgets/calendar.js#L77) of `PrimeFaces.widget.Calendar`

```
<p:calendar widgetVar="calendarWV">
</p:calendar>
```

**javascript**

```
PF('calendarWV').getDate()
```